# How can I use a ringtone that was made by Apple for a local notification? (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, localnotification

I am developing an app that wakes you up after a certain amount of time, and when it is time to wake up I would like to have the local notification play the Marimba ringtone, how would I do this in Swift code? (I don't want to have to download the actual sound file for the ringtone)

```
// create a new alarm/notification
    let notification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.category = "wakeUpAlarms"
    notification.alertAction = "turn off the alarm"
    notification.alertBody = "Time to wake up!"
    notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10)

// instead of UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName, I want the sound name to 
// be one of the iPhone ringtones that are located in the "Sounds" page of 
// such as Marimba the settings app
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Comment: Can you show some code or examples of what you've been working on in order to improve this question? Currently it's too broad and needs some examples of what you've tried to solve this for yourself.

Comment: How do I add a code snippet?

Comment: You can edit your question to paste in code.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Okay I posted the code

Answer (score 0):

You can only use sounds that are a part of the main bundle, which means you have to keep the sound files in the build of the app when submitted to the app store.

1. `UILocalNotification Class Reference`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html
2. `Local and Push Notification Programming Guide` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103